# How to rewrite a page url

Tags: pages, redirect, htaccess

I added a page to my WordPress, I wanted to rewrite the url of the page to a more user friendly one .

`https://localhost/wordpress/page?name=name+of+the+page`

To :

`https://localhost/wordpress/page/name+of+the+page`

If tried to create a htaccess file in my theme directory

```
 function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^page/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php', 'top');
 }
 add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

I tried to redirect it to my index page to see if it works with this link :

`https://localhost/wordpress/page/some+random+string`

but it renders out the not found page, please help

Answer (score 1):

You can change page URL from the page editor.

If you want to make changes for all the pages. You can go to

> settings -> general settings -> permalink

and change it to your desired value.

To change for a single page, modify your .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^phones$ /?page_id=1081 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I want to change it for a specific page not all the website, and how to set  the variables used in the link ?

Comment: @user297904 I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Please I am a begginer in rewrite rule and htaccess file can you tell me exactly which patter to user when I want to match every url like this   `localhost/phone_numbers/france` and redirect it to `localhost/phone_numbers?country=france`